# Phone regex validation for Argentina

Tags: regex, phone-number

I figured out a regular expresion for my country's phone but I've something missing.

The rule here is:  `(Area Code) Prefix - Sufix`

- Area Code could be 3 to 5 digits
- Prefix could be 2 to 4 digits.
- Area Code + Prefix is 7 digits long.
- Sufix is always 4 digits long
- Total digits are 11.

I figured I could have 3 simple regex chained with an OR "|" like this:

```
/(\(?\d{3}\)?[- .]?\d{4}[- .]?\d\d\d\d)|(\(?\d{4}\)?[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\d\d\d\d)|(\(?\d{5}\)?[- .]?\d{2}[- .]?\d\d\d\d)/
```

The thing I'm doing wrong is that `\d\d\d\d` doesn't match only 4 digits for the sufix, for example:   (011) 4740-5000 which is a valid phone number, works ok but if put extra digits it will also return as a valid phone number, ie: (011) 4740-5000000000

Comment: It looks like the common suffix `\d\d\d\d` is repated in all three patterns. `aX|bX|cX` is just `(a|b|c)X`. And why `\d\d\d\d` instead of `\d{4}` ?

Comment: The real problem is phone numbers are never this simple. [Wikipedia:Telephone numbers in Argentina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Argentina) Are you sure you want to be this strict?

Comment: Related (Spanish SO): *[Validar teléfonos argentinos con una expresión regular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/136325/127)*.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `^` and `$` to match whole string

For example `^\d{4}$` will match exactly 4 digits not more not less.

Here is the complete regex pattern

```
^((\(?\d{3}\)? \d{4})|(\(?\d{4}\)? \d{3})|(\(?\d{5}\)? \d{2}))-\d{4}$
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/cQ6fN7/2)

---

As per your regex pattern delimiter can be `-`,`.` or single space then try

```
^((\(?\d{3}\)?[-. ]?\d{4})|(\(?\d{4}\)?[-. ]?\d{3})|(\(?\d{5}\)?[-. ]?\d{2}))[-. ]?\d{4}$
```

Answer (score 1):

This pattern works fine for me:

```
/^\\(?(\d{3,5})?\\)?\s?(15)?[\s|-]?(4)\d{2,3}[\s|-]?\d{4}$/
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Original poster hasn't been online on SO for a long time, for that reason I up-vote your answer without being detective. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the **complete** expression by indicating the start and end with anchors. You also don't need alternation for the different lengths.

```
/^(?=(\D*\d){11}$)\(?\d{3,5}\)?[- .]?\d{2,4}[- .]?\d{4}$/
```

Here's the breakdown:

```
(?=(\D*\d){11}$)    is a non-capturing group ensuring that there are 11 digits total,
                     with any number of non-digits amongst them
\(?\d{3,5}\)?[- .]? matches 3-5 digits in parens (area code), followed by a separator
\d{2,4}[- .]?       matches 2-4 digits (prefix), followed by a separator
\d{4}               matches the suffix
```

Comment: This is quite clever, but I think you'll run into problems with the optional parenthesis in `(Area Code)` (for your lookahead). You may have to use some `|` after all.

Comment: Oops - I didn't notice that the parens were optional. Hmmm.

Comment: @ohaal: OK, I've edited the answer to accommodate parens being there or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this in regex101:

```
/^((?:\(?\d{3}\)?[- .]?\d{4}|\(?\d{4}\)?[- .]?\d{3}|\(?\d{5}\)?[- .]?\d{2})[- .]?\d{4})$/
```

[RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW2eI7/1)

- `^` Matches the beginning of a string

  - `(` Beginning of capture group

    - `(?:` Beginning of non-capturing group

      - Your different options for area code & prefix
    - `)` End non-capturing group
    - `[- .]?\d{4}` The last four digits of the phone number
  - `)` End capture group
- `$` Matches the end of a string

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to validate such a phone number, then the following one should suit your needs:

```
^(?=.{15}$)[(]\d{3,5}[)] \d{2,4}-\d{4}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/CQHTgCZh3qGoBLbm)